# In LLVM, how do I get the loop and its instructions?

Tags: llvm

I am currently learning LLVM pass. I managed to create some simple pass, but now I want to get loops and its instructions. I just learned that it is not as simple as getting instructions from functions and basic blocks.

I got some starting code :

```
for (BasicBlock &B : F) 
{
 for (Instruction &Inst : B) 
 {
   //maybe get loops and insts here(?)
 }
}
```

What should I do to get the loops?

Comment: You need [LoopInfo](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1LoopInfo.html), which the pass manager will give you. There are some nice examples of how to use it in the LLVM source.

Comment: where can I find those examples? I have read the sources and cannot find any examples

Comment: `grep -l LoopInfo ~/llvm/llvm/lib/Transforms/**/*.cpp` returns uses in more than 50 files for me, quite a few of those are good examples.

Comment: thanks. I just found it on web version (same link) and I will look into it

Comment: I think you will find that programming goes more smoothly if you have a git checkout of all of the relevant source code. Not just the source code you plan do modify, all of the relevant source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the function from within a loop pass by `BasicBlock::getParent()` in case you need something. To do in a function pass you can initialize `LoopInfo` and use `LoopInfo::getLoopFor(BasicBlock *)`. See: [llvm.org/doxygen/DeadStoreElimination_8cpp_source.html](https://llvm.org/doxygen/DeadStoreElimination_8cpp_source.html)

For each loop all the `LoopPass`es are invoked. For example: [llvm/lib/Transforms/Scalar/LoopInstSimplify.cpp](https://llvm.org/doxygen/LoopInstSimplify_8cpp.html) . You can make changes in one of the loop passes to get started. There are many examples in `llvm/lib/Transforms/Scalar/` directory.

> now I want to get loops and its instructions

You can iterate through all the BasicBlocks of a loop using a graph traversal algorithm like [Depth First](https://llvm.org/doxygen/LoopLoadElimination_8cpp_source.html#l00624), [Reverse Post Order](https://llvm.org/doxygen/LoopInstSimplify_8cpp_source.html#l00078) etc.

To get started with loop transformations, you should also learn about:

- Natural loops
- LoopAccessInfo
- DominatorTree
- Traversal algorithms like  Depth First, Reverse Post Order

Comment: How can I do it in Function Pass instead of Loop Pass?

Comment: Any reason you want to do in a Function pass? You can access the function from within a loop pass by `BasicBlock::getParent()` in case you need something. To do in a function pass you can initialize LoopInfo and use `LoopInfo::getLoopFor(BasicBlock *)`. See: https://llvm.org/doxygen/DeadStoreElimination_8cpp_source.html

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. But I will still try to learn your original answer. Thank you.